# How does "with mouse.Listener" work in pynput?

Tags: python, pynput

I'm trying to understand an example from [the pynput documentation](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#reference).

I understand the general gist, that the code prints a message when the mouse moves/is clicked/etc. I'm just confused about how it does so.

```
 def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print('{0} at {1}'.format(
        'Pressed' if pressed else 'Released',
        (x, y)))
    if not pressed:
        # Stop listener
        return False

with mouse.Listener(
        on_move=on_move,
        on_click=on_click,
        on_scroll=on_scroll) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: What do the docs of whatever module you're using say?

Comment: I'm using pynput. https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#reference

Comment: Including what you understand from reading that documentation, and what specific parts of the docs you had trouble understanding in the question would make it a a stronger one (more narrow and specific as our rules require, less likely to be closed as "too broad").

Comment: ...I mean, if you want an _exact_ definition of how that works, the most definitive answer there is is to read the pynput source code; and a request that we explain that source code to you line-by-line would not be taken well. So is there a more specific question here, one that could clearly be answered more narrowly than with a line-by-line analysis of the pynput source?

Comment: (You'd want to read [`_base.py`](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/blob/c3af9c8132e73/lib/pynput/mouse/_base.py#L179) -- the base `mouse.Listener` class -- and then the more specific implementation for whichever operating system you care about; [`_darwin.py`](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/blob/master/lib/pynput/mouse/_darwin.py#L154) for MacOS, [`_win32.py`](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/blob/c3af9c8132e73/lib/pynput/mouse/_win32.py#L129) for Windows, [`_xorg.py`](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/blob/c3af9c8132e73/lib/pynput/mouse/_xorg.py#L122) for Linux, etc)

Comment: I assumed that it works in similar way as you use it - you assign functions to `pynput` and it executes them when it get mouse event. And `pynput` probably also assing own functions directly to system (Windows/Mac?Linux) and when system get event then it runs these functions (which runs your functions). Eventually it may runs loop which periodically ask system if there is new mouse event - and then it runs your code.